Save command output to a file and to a variable at the same time
Ubuntu 22.04
I have long running command, which prints output to console.
I would like to redirect that command output (stdout and stderr) to a log file immediately while there is some output for the command, and at the same time I would like to have this same output saved to a variable as well. I do not want any rows printed in the console.
Basically I want this:
output=$(${long_running_command} 2>&1)
echo "${output} >> /tmp/file.log"

The output is saved to a variable, this is all good. Only problem with this code above is that output is printed to a log file only after the long_running_command has been finished.
I am looking a way to achieve that log file write happens immediately when the command produces some output.
I have tried this also:
output=$(${long_running_command} >> /tmp/file.log 2>&1)

For this I can get redirection to log file immediately while there is anything outputted. But here the $output variable is completely empty.
Let's say the long_running_command example is the following:
output=$(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo "$(date): Sleep: $i"; sleep $i; done >> /tmp/file.log 2>&1)
echo "$output"

While the command is executing, and I tail the log file, I can get the output immediately, while it happens. But the issue is, the $output variable is completely empty.
# tail -100f /tmp/file.log
Wed Aug 14 10:40:20 PM EEST 2024: Sleep: 1
Wed Aug 14 10:40:21 PM EEST 2024: Sleep: 2
Wed Aug 14 10:40:23 PM EEST 2024: Sleep: 3
Wed Aug 14 10:40:26 PM EEST 2024: Sleep: 4
Wed Aug 14 10:40:30 PM EEST 2024: Sleep: 5

# output=$(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo "$(date): Sleep: $i"; sleep $i; done >> /tmp/file.log 2>&1)
# echo "$output"

<--- nothing, empty row


If you really need a variable containing the command output after your command finishes why not just read the contents of the file into the variable at that time e.g. long_running_command > /tmp/file.log; IFS= read -rd '' output < /tmp/file.log? Storing a whole file's contents in a variable is usually not the best approach to solving any problem though, there's probably better ways to do whatever it is you're trying to do. This sounds like an XY problem.

This looks like a job for tee ...
If you wish to capture all output (stdout + stderr) in the variable:
$ output="$(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do date; ./do_some_stuff; sleep 1; done 2>&1 | tee -a file.log )"

Where:

./do_some_stuff - does not exist so it should generate an error
2>&1 - redirect stderr to stdout
tee -a file.log - split input into 2 streams; one stream is -appended to file.log, second stream goes to stdout

Results:
$ typeset -p output
declare -- output="Wed Aug 14 15:01:04 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:05 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:06 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:07 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:08 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory"

$ cat file.log
Wed Aug 14 15:01:04 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:05 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:06 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:07 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:01:08 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory

One approach if you wish stderr to only go to the file:
$ output="$(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do date; ./do_some_stuff; sleep 1; done 2>>file.log | tee -a file.log )"

Where:

2>>file.log - explicitly append stderr to file.log so ...
only stdout is piped to tee -a file.log

Results:
$ typeset -p output
declare -- output="Wed Aug 14 15:02:21 CDT 2024
Wed Aug 14 15:02:22 CDT 2024
Wed Aug 14 15:02:23 CDT 2024
Wed Aug 14 15:02:25 CDT 2024
Wed Aug 14 15:02:26 CDT 2024"

$ cat file.log
Wed Aug 14 15:02:21 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:02:22 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:02:23 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:02:25 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory
Wed Aug 14 15:02:26 CDT 2024
bash: ./do_some_stuff: No such file or directory


Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need :)

Actually, I forgot to mention, while using this "tee" command, I will lose the script return code. When I get an error, this gives me 0  (echo "$?")

@RaulKaubi you may want to see if the PIPESTATUS[] array could be of use (eg, see this; it gets tricky since PIPESTATUS[] is being set within a subshell and will 'disappear' upon exiting the subshell; one option might be to dump the array contents to another file and then process that file for exit codes, eg, x=$(./invalid_script | grep hello; typeset -p PIPESTATUS > pipe.out 2>&1); for my examples it's even trickier since the error is embedded within the for loop which generates its own return code upon exiting ....

if you don't need the actual return code but rather to know if there was an error then another option would be to force all stderr output to yet another file (eg, 2>stderr.out) and then test if the file is empty; for multiple commands/pipes you'd probably want to look at each separate command writing to a different stderrX.out file

if you can't get a working solution re: capturing return codes (or determining error status) then I'd suggest asking a new question

Ok, thanks. I will think of something.
